# Easier/Correct way to know when to load the whole page or only part of it

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

I've implemented some simple pages where there are, a header, a content area and a footer.

```
<div id=header></div>
<div id=content></div>
<div id=footer></div>
```

After clicking on an anchor/link, I use ajax to send a request and then, load the html - obtained from the response plus some work(script) over it - into the content area. All done according to the respective resources(urls).

```
    $("#main-menu a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({url:pageurl,success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#content').html(data);
        }});

        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

The script is on the index.html (treated as 'welcome file'), and, from it, I can load the content. But, here is the problem: when I access directly one resource by the url, that is, without clicking on an element - for example, *site.com/sports*, my server will return the page related to sports with no header or footer. 
To solve this, I'm checking, on the server, for a parameter on the request called 'ajax'; if it's true, it respond with the specific data for the request. But if 'ajax' is false or not informed, then I send header and footer together.

**Am I doing this correctly? Is there another way to do this? Is there some good book/article where i can find this answer?**

Comment: Why would you access them directly?

Comment: The server side is only html or do you use PHP ?

Comment: @BabyAzerty My server side rely on java servlets

Comment: @DaveNewton it's common for any user to access a(n) url directly, like site.com/new_promotion, where I access directly the content for the promotion, and not the home page.

Comment: Then you're trying to shoehorn too much functionality into a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by friendly_url if you`re using apache.
At htaccess, you can hide index.html, and call the page by a GET.
Apache will automaticaly changes this to site.com/index.html?page=anything